Remove empty plot section of long ggplot2 plot
I have a very long plot done with ggplot2 intended to be scrolled along in a Shiny app.
ggplot2 plots a big chunk of unused area at the beginning of the plot, and at the end.
Is there any way to avoid this behavior?
I make the plot like this:
mydata <- data.frame(time=1:1000, value=rnorm(1000, mean=10, sd=2))
P <- ggplot2::ggplot(mydata, ggplot2::aes(x=time, y=value)) +
  ggplot2::geom_line(linewidth=0.5) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(breaks=mydata$time) +
  ggplot2::theme_light()
grDevices::pdf(file="test0.pdf", height=2, width=200)
print(P)
grDevices::dev.off()

And I want to remove this unused area marked with the red X at the beginning of the plot, as well as the area at the end of the plot.


The code you provided doesn't produce the figure. You can try:  scale_x_continuous(breaks=mydata$time, expand=c(0,0)

perfect thanks! was not aware of expand
